# How can Select arrays from associate array in php on the basis on element

Tags: php, array

I have an array **`"$arrItems['items']"`** in which 5 more arrays(associate array) and each array contain **5 element(f_name,l_name,contact,address,seller_id)**.
Actually I want to get all those **arrays(from** **"$arrItems['items']")**  in which element of seller_id is 1 like  **"seller_id"=>1**
Code given below. Guide me how to use foreach loop or else . . .

```
array(5)
{
[0] =>
array(5)
{
["f_name"] =>
string(3) "abc"
["l_name"] =>
string(3) "xyz"
["contact"] =>
string(5) "12345"
["address"] =>
string(3) "xyz"
["seller_id"] =>
string(1) => "1"
}
[0]=>
array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
string(1)=>"1"
}
[1]=>
array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
string(1)=>"5"
}
[2]=>
array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
string(1)=>"1"
}
[3]=>
array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
string(1)=>"1"
}
[4]=>
array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
string(1)=>"3"
}
}
```

Comment: You should post it to stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) php function.

```
$filtered = array_filter(
    $arrItems['items'],
    function ($item) {
        return isset($item['seller_id']) && $item['seller_id'] == 1;
    }
);
```

Comment: I think the answer should provide some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Fortunatly** am giving answer of my own question

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($arrItems['items'] as $i => $row) {
    if ($row['seller_id'] != 1) {
        // Ignore row if seller_id is not 1
        continue;
    }

    // here you got only elements with seller_id = 1
    // so you can add them to a new array
    $arr[] = $row;
}

// After the loop (foreach) in $row you get only elements with seller_id 1.
// If they must be in $arrItems['items'] use it
$arrItems['items'] = $arr;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrItems['items']);
echo '</pre>';
```

The Output is :

```
Array
(
    [f_name] => abc
    [l_name] => xyz
    [contact] => 12345
    [address] => xyz
    [seller_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [f_name] => abc
    [l_name] => xyz
    [contact] => 12345
    [address] => xyz
    [seller_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [f_name] => abc
    [l_name] => xyz
    [contact] => 12345
    [address] => xyz
    [seller_id] => 1
)
```